# Is the series $\sum_{x=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2x^3 -x^2}$ convergent?

Tags: real-analysis

$$\sum_{x=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2x^3 -x^2} $$

My answer was it is convergent because $$ \frac{1}{2x^3 -x^2} < \frac{1}{2x^3 -x^3} = \frac{1}{x^3} $$ and $$\sum_{x=1}^\infty \frac{1}{x^3} $$ is convergent.

Can anyone please double check if I was right?
Many thanks

Comment: You are right..

Comment: Just make sure you note the terms are positive.

Comment: The strict inequality is not correct for $x=1$ (in fact you do not need it strict), but it does not matters for the convergence. Sum of positive numbers, upper bounded by a finite number. Convergent

Comment: x>1 here right ?